# How long do I have access to deleted posts?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

The following post has been deleted and I still want to refer to the information ([it is in my favorites](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/what-are-the-must-have-tools-for-amazon-cloud-development))

How long will I be able to see this post until it is permanently purged?

Comment: What favo(u)rites? They have been deleted (Oh, the irony)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the entire history of Stack Exchange, I've only ever seen two posts that have been permanently purged.  One was the "boat programming" one.  The other was a very contentious "how do compilers work" question.  Both questions were asked on Stack Overflow; neither should have been purged IMHO.

AFAIK it is SE's policy to keep deleted records forever (my two examples notwithstanding).  But there's not a lot of information in the post you referenced; it would be easy enough to copy it somewhere, just in case.

Comment: Thank you... actually I was wondering a few months ago where that boat programming Q was, so I could remember why it was so popular in the early days. I guess I'll never know.

Comment: It's a shame, really.  The principals considered it a question asked in bad faith.  Of course, now we have football spammers, Sumar, Goma and other far more disruptive individuals to worry about.

Comment: I don't have any background on Sumar and Goma... not sure what that refers to . I've been off this site after the scope was changed refined and I got left out of the new mindset.  (on a boat you might say)

Comment: Goma is this site's most notorious troll. He's currently eating a suspension until 2017.

Comment: Ironically, the boat programming question was the subject of a [Stack Exchange blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/podcast-50/).  It was chosen as the favorite question asked during that period, until they realized that it was a joke question.  Then they burned it with the fire of a thousand suns.  [This is the only remnant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18596/102937) that is left.

Comment: Just a sidenote: While questions do not get purged from the database, as Robert noted, occasionally a revision (or two) that has private information will get purged upon request (yes, people sometimes post their passwords and credit card information on a public site on the internet).

Comment: @makerofthings7 For more about the boat question (including a copy of the question), you can see this MSO post: [What is the boat programming meme about?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/158605)

Comment: @Rachel: All of the decent mirrors of the question died a long time ago.  WebArchive only captured some of the text.  Unless you know of a link that contains the entire post; that would be really cool. :)

Comment: Here is one archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20100426125115/http://www.mattmcdole.com/boat/

Comment: @makerofthings7: That's basically the same one that is linked at the post Rachel linked.  Are you seeing any pictures?  Maybe they're getting blocked here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey archive.org doesn't save images at all due to storage requirements